# Triggering the keypress event on the angular boostrap ui typeahead directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm using the [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) typeahead directive. I need to prebind the value of the field (easy), and then trigger the type-ahead search functionality, but there seems no way to do the latter programmatically.

Is there a way to emulate the keypress change event that must be triggering the lookup function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look into the bootstrap-ui source code. It seems the bootstrap-ui use the ngModel.$parser to inspect the change of ngModel. [BOOTSTRAP-UI source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/0.12.0/src/typeahead/typeahead.js#L190)(line: 190)

So I create a directive try to trigger $parser with

```
ngModel.$setViewValue('t');
```

And it works.

Here is [DEMO DIRECTIVE PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/niBpNZSWd4Yhbe6xVfMp?p=preview).

And here is [angular $parser&$setViewController document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Hope this can work. : )